# making carousel pure java script

Tags: javascript

i want to make carousel pure java script as like bootstrap  .
    i make this code pen :http://codepen.io/mh_samih/pen/qmmYoN  but how i can use design pattern to   create my carousel function as like bootstrap or how i can optimize my code , and thank you ;
    enter code here /*

```
// ====================================
I used this pen to make carousel pure js  http://codepen.io/info2grow/pen/doLvZo?editors=1010
// =====================================
and i make function indicators and dotcolor : >

*/
// Slider 
var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
   // push All Element in Array  
    arr = carousel.querySelectorAll('.item'),
    dot = carousel.querySelectorAll('.indicators .dot'),
    current = 0,
    img = carousel.querySelector('.item > img'),
    item = carousel.querySelector('.item ');


   window.onresize = function(){
    carousel.style.height = img.height + 'px';
    item.style.height = img.height + 'px';
   }



// Display First Element in Array 
arr[current].style.left = 0;

// change background-color for  First Indicators 
dot[current].setAttribute("class", "dot active");


// Function For Get Previous Element in Array 
function prevSlide(){
var prev;
    if(current === 0){
        prev = arr.length - 1
    }else{
        prev = current - 1;
    }

    // setup prev and current for animation
    arr[prev].style.left = '-100%';
    arr[current].style.left = 0;
    // add class
    arr[prev].setAttribute("class", "item slideInLeft");
    arr[current].setAttribute("class", "item slideOutRight");

    // Update Current Position 
    current = prev ;
    colorDot();

}

// Function For Get Next Element in Array
function nextSlide(){
var next;
    if(current === (arr.length -1) ){
        next = 0
    }else{
        next = current + 1 ;
    }

    // setup next and current for animation
    arr[next].style.left = '100%';
    arr[current].style.left = 0;
    // add class
    arr[next].setAttribute("class", "item slideInRight");
    arr[current].setAttribute("class", "item slideOutLeft");

    // Update Current Position 
    current = next ;
    colorDot();


}

// Function For Indicators 
function indicator(n){
    if(n <  current){

    arr[n].style.left = '-100%';
    arr[current].style.left = 0;
    // add class
    arr[n].setAttribute("class", "item slideInLeft");
    arr[current].setAttribute("class", "item slideOutRight");
    current = n;
    }
else if(n > current){
    // setup next and current for animation
    arr[n].style.left = '100%';
    arr[current].style.left = 0;
    // add class
    arr[n].setAttribute("class", "item slideInRight");
    arr[current].setAttribute("class", "item slideOutLeft");
    current = n ;
}else{
    current = n;
}
    colorDot();



} 

 function colorDot(){

    var i; 
    for(i =0; i < dot.length; i++){
        dot[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    dot[current].classList.add('active');
}
```